# mono + mysql = slow?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, mono

Why does a very simple script which inserts 26,000 records into a mysql database (myisam, no transactions) take 13 seconds in the php implementation, and then 35-50 seconds using mono+mysql connector?

I thought asp.net was faster than php? Could the problem be the mono mysql connector is "platform independent", so the performance just stinks? or does asp.net suffer more overhead than php when it comes to executing each query?

Aren't there any native linux binaries for mysql connector for mono that may be faster?

Comment: Perhaps PHP is transparently recycling connections and mono is opening and closing a new connection for each row?

Comment: Not directly solving the problem, but if you're doing one row per insert, you could rewrite it to insert multiple rows with one statement - this may help a bit with high-volume inserts (see `INSERT INTO sometable (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (val11,val12,val13),(val21,val22,val23)` ): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Comment: No, this is not the case. It's a very simple loop over 26,000 items and reusing a MySqlCommand object and executing ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: @amax: Exactly. This way, you'd insert multiple rows with one command - this may be slightly more efficient, for several reasons.

Comment: ASP.Net vs PHP for speed is very hard to get any meaningful statistics out of, I have seen many benchmarks directly conflicting with each other.  Particularly on database access, could be down to server setup.

Comment: Isn't PHP platform independent?  If platform independence leads to performance just stinking, shouldn't PHP 'just stink' too?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of 52,000 insert/update queries, i'm now using StringBuilder (initialized to 1MB size) to construct one long 'replace into' query. It now takes only 3 seconds (on both windows/.net and linux/mono) instead of of 35+ seconds :-)

Thank you Piskvor.

Footnote:
I just simplified the php script to do the same thing (create a giant 'replace into' query), and it still takes 13 seconds vs asp.net's 3!

So, it looks like .NET IS faster at a more basic level (at least where string manipulation is concerned) and was only slower when running many queries due to mysql's suboptimal .net connector.

Comment: This is likely still sub-optimal.  .Net can get still better using query parameters, which allows the runtime to spend less time assembling your query and allows the database to do better at compiling the query.  Most of all it avoids any possibility of injection.

Comment: How would I use parameterized queries with a statement like:

REPLACE INTO `table` (`one`, `two`, `three`) VALUES 
# foreach loop...
(1,2,3),
(4,5,6),
(7,8,9),
(10,11,12),
..
(25000,25001, 25002)